# IDENTITY not generating the seed and increment correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I set my column ID as IDENTITY with seed and increment = 1,1. But, it does not start counting from 1. Instead it starts at 2. When I insert the next row, it sets the ID = 7 and not 2. Why could this be happening and how do I fix it ?

I scripted the table and also checked management studio. It is actually an IDENTITY(1,1).

Comment: Do you have any inserts that are failing, or in a transaction that gets rolled back? Could you show your code that you're using to insert a row, and the create table script for the table?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I am inserting via management studio. I will try with a SQL statement and get back.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Okay. So, with a sql statement, I actually increases the ID by 1.

Comment: I would suggest that you really shouldn't care what the ID is.  You should not write any code or build any system that is dependent on it being contiguous, or starting from 1.  It's just a generated ID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IDENTITY` does not guarantee a contiguous set of values with no gaps. If this is what you need, you should consider something else (e.g. rolling your own serializable `MAX+1` solution). All kinds of things can create gaps:

- an INSERT that fails
- a transaction that is rolled back
- [this bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/alwayson-failover-results-in-reseed-of-identity)
- a subsequent DELETE (which can also ruin your own solution too)
- etc. etc.

Comment: Wow ! I was completely unaware of these things. I wonder why people use identity when it does not really guarantee anything.

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT Because if left alone, it guarantees uniqueness on that column in cases of concurrency

Answer (score 4):

It's by Design. There is NO GUARANTEE of consecutive-ness for IDENTITY Column.

See the response from **Microsoft** to this "Bug" Report: [Identity Column jumps by Seed value](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/743300/identity-column-jumps-by-seed-value).

> Posted by Microsoft on 1/25/2013 at 3:38 PM
>
> Thanks for your feedback. This behavior is actually by design as we
>   try to guarantee uniqueness of the ID rather than making sure we don't
>   have gaps. As a result, we do skip some values just in case in certain
>   scenarios so that we don't have any issues around accidentally
>   repeating numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the table is empty, SQL server will remember the last identity it used.  If you want to reset it back to 1 try this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('Customer', RESEED, 0)
```

Comment: This isn't going to go very well if they already have a value like 2 or 7. When they get to 2 or 7 they will either end up with a duplicate or, if the IDENTITY column is also the primary key, a primary key violation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Agreed.  As I understood it the OP had an empty table, and didn't understand why when he inserted values they didn't start with 1.

Comment: yes but if you execute DBCC CHECKIDENT('Customer', RESEED) after reseting it to 0 it will create the next highest identity available value on next insert.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I truncated the table and did a single insert statement. The identity began with 1. But, is it guaranteed that identity start from 1 after a table is truncated ?

Comment: Yes, truncating the table will reset the identity.

Comment: Two things: (1) the RESEED check will only work then when the table is empty. He can't use it to restore the values that were "lost" when he inserted 2 and then 7. (2) Truncating will reset the identity, but that doesn't mean the next successful insert will yield 1. For the same reasons that the first insert in the question didn't yield 1 - obviously some other insert was attempted first.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Id_Table (
        [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1), Value INT);
GO

INSERT INTO Id_Table (Value)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);
GO

DELETE FROM Id_Table
WHERE ID = 1 OR  ID = 3 OR ID = 5 OR ID >7
GO

SELECT * FROM Id_Table

DBCC CHECKIDENT('Id_Table', RESEED, 0)  --<-- Reseed to any smallest number
DBCC CHECKIDENT('Id_Table', RESEED)     --<-- Reseed without providing any seed value
```

**SQL SERVER Message**

```
Checking identity information: current identity value '10', current column value '0'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
Checking identity information: current identity value '0', current column value '7'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Reseed the table to Zero and then just execute the DBCC command without any seed value and it will reseed the Identity value to next highest available Identity value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's pretty simple to resolve this problem.  I am using the Visual Studio 2013 designer, SQL Server Object Explorer.  Bring up the offending table in Design View, select the Identify field and pull up the properties.  I merely updated the Identity Seed and Increment values and then clicked the Update button.  This fixed it for me.

While Identity increments aren't guaranteed, we have come to expect that they should add 1 to highest increment entered thus far.