# SQL Server identity insert error

Tags: sql-server-2008, identity-insert

I set the identity inset on with "identity increment =1, identity seed=1". but when I tried it, the first id is 1, the second id is 4, the third is 8, the fourth is 14. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what the issue maybe?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153310/identity-not-generating-the-seed-and-increment-correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use a try catch block find out the error. May me some of your insert fails. that's the reason identity keep incrementing and saves with successful value on that instance